# C# Forms | Code for Metro Framework Message Box Button

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox, metroframework

How can I put a code that will be executed when I click a Button in MetroFramework Message Box. I am still learning how to use hte framework. I found it difficult because unlike the regular Message Box, you can code through the use of Dialog Result. But I don't know if it has a counterpart in the Metro Framework. Thanks in advance! :)

Below is my code. I don't know how can I make an If Statement from the YesNo button.

```
 MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "\n\nContinue Logging Out?", "EMPLOYEE MODULE | LOG OUT", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to use the reference of the MetroFramework. This code will let you insert your MetroFramework UI events like `MetroMessageBox`without typing the whole code extension again on the same form.

```
using MetroFramework;
using MetroFramework.Forms;
```

Then insert this code:

```
DialogResult dr = MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "\n\nContinue Logging Out?", "EMPLOYEE MODULE | LOG OUT", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
if(dr == DialogResult.Yes)
{
     YourEventsHere;
}
else
{
     YourElseEvents;
}
```

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response!! :)

Comment: @KuysChan did I help you with my answer?

Comment: Yes kuys! Salamat po :D

Answer (score 0):

`MetroMessageBox` function exactly the same as a normal `MessageBox`. Only the skin is different. You have to use the `DialogResult`.

Here is it's source code :

```
public sealed class MetroMessageBox : MetroForm
```

If `DialogResult` is not enough, then you have to create your own form.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) just like `MessageBox`:

```
var result = MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(
    this,
    "\n\nContinue Logging Out?", "EMPLOYEE MODULE | LOG OUT",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
    MessageBoxIcon.Question
);

if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    // Do Yes stuff
}
else
{
    // No stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void hand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "OK", "message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
    }
    private void button2_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "OK", "message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }

    private void btninformation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Data saved successfully. \n Thank You.", "Successfull", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

for more info : 
see this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzVNRsssG5I&list=PLB2zkXAmYx8qrLCll1jJqAo8aJzsks1S5&index=3&t=339s